# BeautifulSoup in Python: Get series of tags where first exactly matches input

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using the `BeautifulSoup` module in Python 3.10 to get HTML data off a web page.

The way this web page is structured, there's a bunch of `<h1>` tags which section the web page. Some of these will look like `<h1 class="title"><img attributes/> Text</h1>`, and some will lack the `img` element but are otherwise identical.

Suppose I start with a string called `name` and a BeautifulSoup object called `soup`. This BeautifulSoup object contains several `<h1>` tags as described above, each of which is followed by more HTML code. Suppose further that no two `<h1>` elements contain identical text.

I'd like to compile a function which does the following:

1. Searches the BeautifulSoup object for a `<h1>` element which contains a string that, excluding the `<img>` content, exactly matches the input string `name`.
2. If it's not the last `<h1>` tag in the BeautifulSoup object, return everything from that `<h1>` tag until the next `<h1>` tag. The latter tag shouldn't be included in the return, but the former tag can be optionally included or excluded. If it *is* the last `<h1>` tag, return everything from that tag to the end of the object.

I'm only just learning BeautifulSoup. I know how to use `.find()` or `.find_all()` to track down which `<h1>` tag matches, but I don't know how to return all the following blocks as well.

Comment: I have guess of an idea what the target might be, but to be sure you should improve your question, cause there are so much unknown (children or sibling, ...). May take a minute or two to read How to create [mcve], thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you crawl data using BeautifulSoup. All HTML tags will be written down. Just use a loop to find that checks for your image's existence or not.